# CKEditor 4 and CSP problems

Tags: ckeditor4.x

I am having some trouble with CKE 4. Where I work they decided to enable the Content security policy sitewide.

So now CKE and custom plugins are not working but they want to continue using the editor until everything will be switched to CKE 5.

I sincerely do not know how to solve this since CSP or is enabled or is not enabled. I know about the hash but is supported only in chrome and edge.

Does anyone already have faced this issue?

I tried to look online but I do not think there are easy options, unless they detect when CKE is going to be used and omit the CSP headers only on that case.

Comment: Have you solved this issue?